# Why did I revise the LaunchScreen.xib but the simulator screen didn't change?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13

Here is the screenshot of simulator and LaunchScreen.xib, hope someone can tell me what's happened?

[image: simulator screen]

[image: screenshot of LaunchScreen.xib]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Run app after **Deleting app from simulator** or **simulator->Hardware->Erase All Content and Setting**

Comment: Thanks for all that, it's all good now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to caching in Springboard. If you absolutely 100% need to see your new launch screen now, delete the app from the simulator (or, if that doesn't work, reset the Simulator) and re-run.